# Installing Anti-Virus on Availability Group databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, configuration

Is it worth the risk to use Anti-Virus on Availability Group databases? Even following the guidelines given by Microsoft in [How to choose antivirus software to run on computers that are running SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309422/choosing-antivirus-software-for-computers-that-run-sql-server).

We are planning to install Kaspersky.

It is a department decision to have all servers installed with Anti-Virus.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, whatever box it's on shouldn't be doing to sort of activity that leads to virus and malware. If you follow that guide things for the most part should be fine to install the software but it will still be using some hardware resources.

I'd recommend you just follow the Microsoft laid path. You may also want to talk to the software vendor to make sure they don't have any specific recommendations. Beyond that just beware that the software will still have processor overhead as well. You'll likely not want to have SQL Server maintenance jobs at the same time as whatever scanning this virus software scheduled to run. - [zane](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10414/zane)